# ListView data showing undefined in KendoUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

HTML Code.. I am working for learning purpose, therefore I used Sample code

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
    <div class="product-view k-widget">
        <dl>
            <dt>  Title  </dt>
            <dd>  #:Title#   </dd>
            <dt>  Deetail  </dt>
            <dd>  #:Deetail#   </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
</script>
```

parameterMap:

```
else if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {                                        
    return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models)
};
```

JavaScript:

```
var listView = $("#listView").kendoListView({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    template: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
    editTemplate: kendo.template($("#editTemplate").html())
}).data("kendoListView");`
```

API Call:

```
read: {
    type: "GET",
    url: "XYZ"+value,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false
},
```

Controller Code:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetSpecificationDetail(int id)
{
    Type type= new Type();
    List<Type> spdetails = db.Type.Where(i => i.typeId == id).ToList();
    if (spdetails == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(spdetails);
}
```

As a result I am getting data for first row but for rest all rows it shows "unidentified"

Answer (score 0):

I got answer

var spdetails = db.TypeDetails.Where(i => i.TypeId == id).Select(s=> new TypeDetailsView{ TypeId=s.TypeId,Details=s.TypeDetails,TypeTitle=s.TypeTitle}).ToList();